# Bootstrap modal scroll back when close

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Method to reproduce

1. open https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#live-demo
2. open DevTools in Edge
3. click "Launch demo modal" button
4. run `$("#static-backdrop").scrollIntoView()` in DevTools. I find the web page scrolls down to "Static backdrop" section
5. close the modal by clicking "Close" or "X" or outside modal. I find the web page scrolls back to "Live demo" section

Can I keep the position when I close the modal?